# How can I get Realtime update from firestore in my react-native application? I want to prevent multiple logs in from same user from different devices

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on one app in react-native. I want to do this kind of functionality.
1)When the user will log in from 1st device with their credential at that time I am storing device ID in my firestore database.
now, If the user will do sign in from 2nd device with the same credential at that time I am going to log out that user from 1st device. I have implemented that logic.
But the issue is this is not happening in real-time. When I will restart the 1st device's application at that time this logic works.
Is there any type of method that triggers when my database updates?
I want this logic to works immediately when the user logs in from another device with the same ID.

```
const onAuthStateChanged = async (user) => {
setUser(user);
if (user) {
  //here i am checking for token 

  await firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(user.email)
    .get()
    .then((documentSnapshot) => {
      const data_device = documentSnapshot.data();

      if (device_id != data_device.device_token) {
        alert('you are signned in other device'); //and if not as same then logout
        logout();
      }
    });
}
if (inisiallizing) setInisiallizing(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` only run when the `authState` changed (Login, logout, register) and its state is run on it own (not run in multiple environment, devices).

As your usecase, I think you should listen to a `documents` on Firestore that store your `deviceId`

```
firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .doc(user.email)
  .onSnapshot((doc) => {
    // Your logic to logout here
  })
```

The above code will run everytime document `firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.email)` has update

Comment: Yes, Thank you @ThanhLe for your answer. It worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome @Milan. I'm founder of https://refiapp.io/ - A tool to make developers less painful when interacting with Firestore DB. Hope it help your development workflow